# Does there always exist $y$ such as $x^Ty=\lceil x^Tb\rceil-x^Tb$ is always true?

Tags: relations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Maybe my question is easy but I need some help since I do not see how to answer it.

I have a set of $n$ **nonnegative integers** $b_i$ with $i=1,...,n$ and a set of **rational** $x_i$ in the interval $[0,1]$ for all $i=1,...,n$.

Is it always possible to find a set of $n$ nonnegative integers $y_i$ with $i=1,...,n$ such as

$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i=\left\lceil\sum_{i=1}^nx_ib_i\right\rceil-\sum_{i=1}^nx_ib_i?$$

Example with $n=2$, $b=(26,10)$ and $x=(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{2})$:
the relation holds with $y=(4,0)$.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Explain what you mean by y = (4,0).  Same for b and x.